# Browse json by value in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
    "brands": [
        {
            "name": "CarBrand1",
            "models": [
                {
                    "name": "CarModel1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "CarModel2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "CarModel3"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "CarBrand2",
            "models": [
                {
                    "name": "CarModel1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "CarModel2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "CarModel3"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've got a JSON like this and I would like to go inside `CarBrand1` to get every car models of `CarBrand1`. I can do

```
json.brands[0]
```

to get `CarBrand1` car models or

```
json.brands[1]
```

to get `CarBrand2` car models. But what if I want to get `CarBrand2` car models by the brand name value ("name": "CarBrand2") ?

Something like

```
json.brands['CarBrand1']
```

(but of course it's not the right way)

Comment: you can use `json.brands.find((c) => c.name == "CarBrand1")`

Comment: You iterate and compare. There are libraries that may help, but the underlying implementation is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no simple way to access objects by property names without iterating and comparing. I guess the simplest way is to use the `find` function:

```
json.brands.find((c) => c.name == "CarBrand1")
```

Note that if you often need to access the brands by name, I suggest you create a lookup dictionary of some sort. For example:

```
lookup = []; 
js.brands.forEach((c, i) => lookup[c.name] = c)

lookup["CarBrand1"] // --> {name: "CarBrand1", models: Array(4)}
```

Comment: json.brands.find((c) => c.name == "CarBrand1").models

Comment: @EranGeva if the name doesn't exist, what you propose gives an error.  But yeah, in the end OP will need to use `.models` on the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a reusable function that takes the car name as a parameter and return the car models array:

```js
var car = {
    "brands": [
        {
            "name": "CarBrand1",
            "models": [
                {
                    "name": "CarModel1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "CarModel2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "CarModel3"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "CarBrand2",
            "models": [
                {
                    "name": "CarModel1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "CarModel2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "CarModel3"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
function getCarModel(name){
  for(var i=0; i<car.brands.length; i++){
    if(car.brands[i].name === name){
      return car.brands[i].models;
    }
  }
}

console.log(getCarModel("CarBrand2"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
var json_data = {
  "brands": [{
      "name": "CarBrand1",
      "models": [{
          "name": "CarModel1"
        },
        {
          "name": "CarModel2"
        },
        {
          "name": "CarModel3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "CarBrand2",
      "models": [{
          "name": "CarModel1"
        },
        {
          "name": "CarModel2"
        },
        {
          "name": "CarModel3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

function getCarModelByName(name) {
  var json_array = json_data.brands;
  return json_array.filter(
    function(json_array) {
      if (json_array.name == name) {
        return json_array.models;
      }
    }
  );
}
var model = getCarModelByName('CarBrand2');
console.log(model[0].models)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var jsonObj = {
    "brands": [
        {
            "name": "CarBrand1",
            "models": [
                {
                    "name": "CarModel1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "CarModel2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "CarModel3"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "CarBrand2",
            "models": [
                {
                    "name": "CarModel1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "CarModel2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "CarModel3"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

var res = jsonObj.brands.filter(obj => obj.name == 'CarBrand2');

console.log(res[0].models);
```